# compass/sass issues using Symfony2

Tags: symfony, sass, compass-sass

I am new in using compass and I'd like to use it with sass in my symfony2 project.

I googled how to set the project:
- Installed ruby
- then install Compass/sass.

Assetic bundle is installed, and then I added in the conf.yml:

```
parameters:
  assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/img
  assetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /img
assetic:
  debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
  use_controller: false
  bundles:        [ ]
  filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #sass and compass assetic conf
    sass:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
    compass:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
```

And finally I add in my html.twig

```
{% stylesheets filter="compass" output="assets/css/styles.css"  "@lbTestBundle/Resources/assets/sass/*.scss" %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

when i use the command "assetic:dump" the css file is create but I got the following error :

```
Error Output:
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/local/bin/compass (LoadError)
```

And my css is empty.

Did I missed something? If someone can help me thanks.

Comment: make sure those binaries exist in those locations. does it work to call those binaries from the command line?

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/bin/compass` instead? Also you don't need to add sass with compass as far as I know.

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/compass`. Same error message.

Comment: The problem is that when I tape `compass` or `sass` command in the terminal i can use them, but when I search for them in the `/usr/bin/` i don't find them

Answer (score 4):

l3l0 was nearly there. You have to specify the path to ruby, but the configuration was wrong.

Fixed config.yml:

```
assetic:
  debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
  use_controller: false
  bundles:        [ YourBundleShouldBeThere ]
  # Set path to your ruby
  ruby: /path/to/ruby
  filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #sass and compass assetic conf
    sass:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
    compass:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
```

Next set the correct path to sass and compass. They are normally found in the `bin` folder of the default gem installation dir.

Execute the following command in the terminal and look for *INSTALLATION DIRECTORY*

```
gem environment
```

For production you also need to dump the assets, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

To use compass you need ruby. Please check where you have ruby installed by using `whereis ruby` command in the terminal.

Then add path to ruby in your assetic config:

```
assetic:
  debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
  use_controller: false
  bundles:        [ YourBundleShouldBeThere ]
  ruby:
    bin: /path/to/ruby
  filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #sass and compass assetic conf
    sass:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
    compass:
        bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
```

Comment: I did it, ruby is installed at `usr/bin/ruby`. But adding this line give me an error: `assetic Expected scalar, but got array`

Comment: so maybe `whereis compass` cause /usr/bin/ruby is default path in assetic IIRC. Did you install compass as well using ruby gem ?

Comment: i tried but it doesn't display anything, and i installed it using ruby gem here are my gems: `bundler (1.3.2)chunky_png (1.2.7)compass 0.12.2)fssm (0.2.10)rake (10.0.3)sass (3.2.7)`

Comment: I solved this by running

`gem update --system`
and installing compass again:

`sudo gem install compass --pre`
The 1st time i didn't use the argument `--pre`

I don't know what it mean but now the gems are in the `/usr/local/bin` and the .sass and .scss compile.

The question I'm asking to myself now is why do I have the css in double ? the one I write `output="assets/css/styles.css"`and an other one `styles_part_1_test_1.css` both are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just changed the sass and compass path (without "local") and it worked for me:

```
filters:
    sass:
        bin: /usr/bin/sass
    compass:
        bin: /usr/bin/compass
    cssrewrite: ~
```